# Kotlin call of a function

Tags: kotlin

```
 fun add ( value : A, compare : (A, A) -> Int ) : Tree <A> =
        when (this) {
            is Empty -> treeNode(value)
            is Node -> if (compare(value,this.value) < 1) {
                treeNode(this.value,left.add(value,compare),right)
            } else{
                treeNode(this.value,left,right.add(value,compare))
            }
        }
```

I dont understand what the funtion wants when I call it

tree.add(5,?)

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#function-types

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second argument of `tree.add()` should be a function that takes 2 objects of type `A` and returns an integer.

To pass such a function, one option is to use a lambda expression (with braces):

```kotlin
tree.add(5, { a, b -> ... })
```

In Kotlin, we usually pass such lambdas outside the parenthesis of the function call, though. Like this:

```kotlin
tree.add(5) { a, b -> ... }
```

Now let's check the content of the function. In your case, the semantic of the expected function seems to be the same as the [Comparator.compare](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-comparator/compare.html) or [Comparable.compareTo](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-comparable/compare-to.html) functions:

> Compares its two arguments for order. Returns zero if the arguments are equal, a negative number if the first argument is less than the second, or a positive number if the first argument is greater than the second

When `A` is `Int` like in your example, the implementation of the comparison function could simply call `Int.compareTo(Int)`:

```kotlin
tree.add(5) { a, b -> a.compareTo(b) }
```

Another way is to pass a method reference directly instead of a lambda:

```kotlin
tree.add(5, Int::compareTo)
```

---

Note: passing the comparator function as argument to `add` is rather bad design (especially because this function is public), because the comparator can be different for each call adding elements to the tree. It should instead be a property of the tree itself, otherwise the tree could become inconsistent.

Comment: btw `{ a, b -> a - b }` could fail for very large numbers and very small negative numbers (due to overflow). You should use `a.compareTo(b)` instead.

Comment: @k314159 good point, fixed!